# How would I "mass" list strings in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

So I need to list a bunch of emails and when I have to do like 5-10, it's no big deal but the more there are, the harder it gets. And I've seen someone turn this:

```
macy08@gmail.com
ycrist@denesik.info
zieme.wellington@thiel.net
cummings.friedrich@thompson.net
ryan.annalise@collier.com
```

into this all at once:

```
email = ['macy08@gmail.com',
'ycrist@denesik.info',
'zieme.wellington@thiel.net',
'cummings.friedrich@thompson.net',
'ryan.annalise@collier.com']
```

by just typing a few things in the "current Buffer" area. He said he was using regular expression and it kind of looked like this:

```
^([A-Za-z]+)$

"$1",
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: What format is the email list in now?

Comment: It's unclear to me where the emails come from in the beginning. Do you have all the emails in a file and you would like to read that file and convert it into list of emails? You need to be more concise when describing your problem.

Comment: If you have a list of emails separated by newlines, just read the whole mess into a variable and then use `yourvarname.splitlines()` to get a list.

Comment: "Current buffer" isn't a Python thing. If you're asking us how to use a text editor, you're going to have to specify which editor.

Comment: I'm keeping them in a emails.json file. With one email per line and using vscode

Comment: "emails.json file" - This clearly isn't JSON, so that's a poor choice of extension. Anyway, just reading the file in Python and calling `splitlines` would do the job. If you want to embed the list in your source code, you could print it (perhaps to a file) and copy-paste the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it dosn't look like json so it should probably by in a text file,
this will open the file and print it as a list

```py
with open('emails.txt') as f:
    email_list = f.readlines()
print(email_list)
```

or if you want to write it to a json file:

```py
import json
with open('emails.txt') as f:
    email_list = f.readlines()
with open('emails.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(email_list))
```